# reading time stamp from files in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to read when a file is created (or last modified) as it showed in Finder "Date Modified."

Is there any existing method in Cocoa can do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 10.5 or later, you can use [`-[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:).

Answer (score 1):

see `'man stat'` or google `'struct stat'`

Comment: The POSIX stat attributes are distinct from the Cocoa attributes, and OS X is pretty inconsistent about updating them.